# Table with no DELETE or UPDATE operations needs VACUUM?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Documentation says:

> VACUUM reclaims storage occupied by dead tuples. In normal PostgreSQL operation, tuples that are deleted or obsoleted by an update are not physically removed from their table; they remain present until a VACUUM is done.

I have table  with ~ 50 000 `INSERT` and much more `SELECT` operations per day, but there is no `DELETE` or `UPDATE` operations at all on this table.

Question is: do I need periodically `VACUUM` for this table? or in this particular case, this no makes sense at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason why such a table needs to be vacuumed is to *freeze* tuples (mark them as permanently valid) so that they don't disappear when the transaction counter wraps around.

This has to happen only once for each tuple.